# How to get rid of "Validation failed for domain" on Let's Encrypt (ACME prototcol)

Tags: chef-infra, lets-encrypt, acme

I have an issue with one of my domain regarding the domain validation for Let's Encrypt certificate.

One domain is working but the other isn't.
Both are configured identically.

I'm using [chef-acme](https://github.com/schubergphilis/chef-acme).

Answer (score 0):

I removed the IPv6 DNS entries and now everything is working.